# Purpose of Control.Validate()

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to know...

- why `Control.Validate()` exists?
- in which cases it should/n't be used?
- in which cases it could be handy?

Comment: You mean `Invalidate()`? There is no `Validate()` method on `Control`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I guess you mean `ContainerControl`'s `Validate()`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf8t2at(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you an example as the `msdn` does here : [`Control.Validate(Event)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx).

A simple example is when you are trying to "validate" an Email address that the user enters on a `TextBox`. If the e-mail address is not in the standard format (containing "@" and "."), the validation fails, an `ErrorProvider` icon is displayed, and the event is canceled. This example requires that a `TextBox` and `ErrorProvider` control have been created on a form.

And this is the function of it :

> If the `CausesValidation` property is set to `false`, the `Validating` and `Validated` events are suppressed.
>
> If the Cancel property of the `CancelEventArgs` is set to `true` in the `Validating` event delegate, all events that would usually occur after the `Validating` event are suppressed.